# Twisted 16 LineReceiver: No callbacks fired

Tags: python, twisted

I am running a little twisted application for around a year now. It all worked well until end of february. Since then I can't transfer any data between my client and server. I prepared a little example based on my real code:

Server:

```
from twisted.python.filepath import FilePath
from twisted.logger import Logger, textFileLogObserver, globalLogPublisher, globalLogBeginner
from twisted.internet.endpoints import SSL4ServerEndpoint
from twisted.internet.ssl import PrivateCertificate, Certificate
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred
from twisted.internet.task import react
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver
import codecs
import sqlite3
import os


import sys
globalLogBeginner.beginLoggingTo([textFileLogObserver(sys.stdout)])
loggy = Logger()

class Ex_Factory(Factory):
    def __init__(self, loggy):
        self.loggy = loggy
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Ex_Protocol(self.loggy)
class Ex_Protocol(LineReceiver):
    def dataReceived(self,data):
        self.loggy.info('mmm')
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.sendLine(b'hello')
        self.loggy.info('ConMade')
    def __init__(self, loggy):
        self.loggy = loggy
        self.loggy.info('Works')

    def lineReceived(self, data):
        self.loggy.info('I am not called! But why?')

def main(reactor):
    #Set up a SSL-Endpoint
    pemBytes = FilePath(b"private.pem").getContent()
    certificateAuthority = Certificate.loadPEM(pemBytes)
    myCertificate = PrivateCertificate.loadPEM(pemBytes)
    serverEndpoint = SSL4ServerEndpoint(
        reactor, 1234, myCertificate.options(certificateAuthority)
    )
    serverEndpoint.listen(Ex_Factory(loggy))
    return Deferred()
react(main, [])
```

Client:

```
dir="/working_dir"
certname="private.pem"

from twisted.python.filepath import FilePath
from twisted.internet.endpoints import SSL4ClientEndpoint
from twisted.internet.ssl import (PrivateCertificate, Certificate, optionsForClientTLS)
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred, inlineCallbacks
from twisted.internet.task import react
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver
import os
class SendAnyData(LineReceiver):
    deferred = Deferred()
    def connectionMade(self):
        print('ConMade!')
        self.sendLine(b"START")
        self.transport.write(b"START\r\n")
    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print('ConLost!')
        self.deferred.callback(None)
    def lineReceived(self, data):
        line = data.decode("UTF-8")

@inlineCallbacks
def main(reactor):
    def getServerandPort(i):
       return ("1.2.3.4",1234)
    pem = FilePath(b"Certificates/"+certname.encode("UTF-8")).getContent()
    caPem = FilePath(b"Certificates/ca-private-cert.pem").getContent()
    host, port = getServerandPort(0)

    clientEndpoint = SSL4ClientEndpoint(
            reactor, host, port,
            optionsForClientTLS(u"ABC", Certificate.loadPEM(caPem),
                                    PrivateCertificate.loadPEM(pem)),
    )
    factory = Factory.forProtocol(SendAnyData)
    proto = yield clientEndpoint.connect(factory)
    yield proto.deferred

os.chdir(dir)
react(main)
```

When I run the application on two seperate Raspberry Pis using Python 3.4.2 on Debian Jessie, this is the output from the server:

```
2016-04-09T11:44:01+0200 [-] Ex_Factory (TLS) starting on 1234
2016-04-09T11:44:01+0200 [__main__.Ex_Factory#info] Starting factory <__main__.Ex_Factory object at 0xb5f2ee50>
2016-04-09T11:44:49+0200 [__main__#info] Works
2016-04-09T11:44:49+0200 [__main__#info] ConMade
^C2016-04-09T11:46:54+0200 [-] Received SIGINT, shutting down.
2016-04-09T11:46:54+0200 [twisted.protocols.tls.TLSMemoryBIOFactory] (TLS Port 1234 Closed)
2016-04-09T11:46:54+0200 [__main__.Ex_Factory#info] Stopping factory <__main__.Ex_Factory object at 0xb5f2ee50>
2016-04-09T11:46:54+0200 [-] Main loop terminated.
```

Why is there no line, that has successfully been sent from client to server ("START")? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you so much for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunatelly, I got help by tom.prince in the [twisted ticket system](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/8298). He recommended me to print out the reason paramter of the connectionLost callback. I got an SSLv3 error which led me to the problem: The certificates have been expired...